# Nodejs and Tomcat listening on same port number, is this possible

Tags: node.js, tomcat

I have a web application running on tomcat at a particular port number and I would like some way of intercepting http requests made in that web application in a node server.... is this possible?.

I was hoping to use the request information to open another browser displaying info on the request (this is me purely playing with node). 
I have the node server listening on the port using the sample server code below and it works when the tomcat app isnt running... when tomcat is running on the port it doesnt work..

Is there a way to do this?

```
var http = require('http');
   http.createServer(function (req, res) {
   res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
   res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8080);
console.log('Server running at 8080');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two servers need to listen on different ports. But you can use the nodes to proxy the requests to the tomcat. There are some nice modules you might be able to use, I.e: https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy

Comment: thanks for that, i had been looking at that module.... so there is no way to eavesdrop as such?..

Comment: My pleasure.  No, I don' think they can be married together without reverse proxy. Another option is to use standalone reverse proxy(one example is [nginx](http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/) )

Comment: it's works like a middle man sits in-between the client user and a number of servers, that making request to multiple servers on the user's behalf.  In your example, the reverse proxy server talk to tomcat and nodejs. And the user only need to see the proxy server. This wiki explains nicely [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy)